# How to show if ip address exists in AWS instances with AWS SDK on python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, boto

i have a easy question. I need to show, if ip address exists or if ip address does not exists in simple condition. Little part of my code:

```
for i in ec2.instances.all():
    if i.public_ip_address == '192.168.1.1':
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

But please look, if i am starting script, i have:

```
no
no
yes
no
no
no
no
no
no
no
```

So ... It is going to check all list of ip addresses. But i need only one checking. I want to receive result 'yes' or 'no'. How to do in this situation ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily solved by declaring a flag variable and setting it to a desired value once the IP is found.

```
ip_found = False
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    if i.public_ip_address == '192.168.1.1':
        ip_found = True
if ip_found:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

This code sets the `ip_found` flag only once (after initialisation) - when it actually matches `'192.168.1.1'`.